# Make a string into dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary

In the below string we have to get slipt the dict vals with the & and the keys are are LHS and their respective RHS are values in the dict.

Input

```
s = 'term=food&location=New York'
```

Expected Output

```
{term:'food', location:'New York'}
```

I've tried

```
a_dict = dict([s.strip('{}').split("&"),])
pairs=[item.split('=')for item in items]
d = dict(pairs)
```

Help me out

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a short way of doing it

```
s = 'term=food&location=New York'
s = [item.split('=') for item in s.split('&')]

print(dict(s))
```

Outputs:

```
{'term': 'food', 'location': 'New York'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'term=food&location=New York'
a_dict = s.split("&")
pairs=[item.split('=')for item in a_dict]   
d = dict(pairs)
```